# What is the best way to remotely access devices connected to a Linux box?

Tags: linux, windows, vpn, remote

Our team accesses the work network via a Cisco VPN.  We work with devices (PLC, HMI, etc.) that cannot be directly connected to the work network, so we have an isolated network we used when at work.

Now that we are all staying home, we need remote access.  We have a Linux box (jump-host) that is connected to the isolated network and to the work network.  The challenge is that we have to go over the Cisco VPN to get on the work network, but then need to get access to the devices, and the Windows software is not particularly smart (can't proxy, for instance).

We've tried using [tinc](https://www.tinc-vpn.org/), [openvpn](https://openvpn.net), and [sshuttle](https://github.com/sshuttle/sshuttle), but we cannot seem to make any of these work because of interference from the Cisco VPN connection.

Any suggestions are appreciated!!!

Comment: "Best" is subjective, unless you specify what it means. This site strongly stresses the need for _objective_ criteria. If you have other criteria, suggest you include them; also, at least, click [edit] and revise your question to state "allows proxy use when used over Cisco VPN". Note: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_remote_desktop_software#Operating_system_support lists remote servers and clients known to work with Linux.

Comment: Why don't you install Linux on your computer at home ? Can you ask for a reconfiguration of the Cisco VPN?

Comment: Your question is more for https://workplace.stackexchange.com/ than for here. The apparent issue is managerial and organizational and does not seems to be technical